# packets from port 1900 to port 49125

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have a TP-Link Archer C7 router and a Debian 9.4 server that has UFW installed on it. I was looking through the UFW logs and it looks like my router is sending requests to port 49125 of server every 30 seconds. I cannot figure out how to diagnose this.

My router is 192.168.1.1 and my server is 192.168.1.100. Here is an excerpt from the UFW log file. Does anyone know what this could be?

```
Mar 23 22:28:12 mydebianserver kernel: [  769.900902] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:28:32 mydebianserver kernel: [  789.900838] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:28:52 mydebianserver kernel: [  809.900581] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:29:12 mydebianserver kernel: [  829.900395] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:29:32 mydebianserver kernel: [  849.900548] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:29:52 mydebianserver kernel: [  869.900169] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:30:13 mydebianserver kernel: [  890.428246] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:30:32 mydebianserver kernel: [  909.899898] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:30:52 mydebianserver kernel: [  929.899368] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:31:12 mydebianserver kernel: [  949.899450] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:31:32 mydebianserver kernel: [  969.899535] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:31:52 mydebianserver kernel: [  989.899162] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:32:12 mydebianserver kernel: [ 1009.899015] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
Mar 23 22:32:32 mydebianserver kernel: [ 1029.898800] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=287 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49125 LEN=267
```

Comment: Maybe it is the other way around, since port 49125 looks more random than 1900 you might see dropped answer packages, so the server is actually hammering the router on port 1900 which is UPnP. The router answers (it is common but not necessarily good if the router supports UPnP) but the server has no host firewall rule to allow this. Check if the server runs a UPnP client, media browser or similar.

Comment: Yeah, seems like UFW is blocking an answer from the router to the server. The server probably sent some UDP packets to the router and the router responds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDP port `1900` is used for *Simple Service Discovery Protocol* (SSDP), a part of UPnP. The router is probably not sending requests but responding to the request made by your server.

If you don't actually use UPnP for anything, you may want to disable it as it's known for several [security issues](https://blog.rapid7.com/2013/01/29/security-flaws-in-universal-plug-and-play-unplug-dont-play/) and [abuses](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/06/19/pinkslipbot_returns_withupnp_malware_attack/) during years.

Disabling UPnP on your TP-Link Archer C7:

1. Choose menu "Forwarding→UPnP".
2. If Current UPnP Status = Enabled, press button Disable.

This should also stop these lines to appear in your UFW log.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like Plex Media Server was responsible for the scans.